# How do you use a repl with Vagrant?

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm looking at simplifying the initial developer setup at my company by using Vagrant.  On the surface, it seems pretty nice: I write a Vagrantfile once and commit it, and then new developers just install VirtualBox and Vagrant, `git clone` our project's source code, and type `vagrant up`, and they have a running web app, with all the dependencies handled automatically.

The one piece that I'm not sure about is the repl.  It's common to run the command to start a shell with the web server's environment, for experimentation or testing or debugging or whatever.  (I mean something like `rails console`.  I'm sure every web framework has something similar.)

How do Vagrant users typically do this?  Do you just keep a `vagrant ssh` window open, and run your repl in there?  It seems awkward to have to use (potentially) a different window (and operating system) for just this one thing.  But in order to run it natively, I'd need to install the whole development environment natively, which defeats the purpose of Vagrant in the first place.

Am I overthinking this?  Is there some other practice that people typically use for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking this a bit -- most modern deveopment requires an open command prompt or three, having it be SSH'd into a different box isn't really much different than running it locally in many cases.

Another angle for some things -- like code and scaffolding generation -- is to run those on the local box. Since there is that shared folder it will land on the server and you don't need to switch environments.